# How does the deployment of server look like

Tags: c++, networking, client-server, server, hosting

I´m kinda new to these networking stuff, but basically managed to finish server to handle client requests(wan´t it to handle connections to game and help the clients update the game and stuff). I got it working on my localhost (sending files/packets on same PC is working already - i just launch server app and then client app). However, I still wonder how it works in real, if I want to access my server from global network. I understand that I need a hosting. So to sumarize my thoughts:

1. Find hosting - As the server,client or engine code is in C++, do I have to look for hostings specifically for C++ applications?
2. Now the server works this way: I set up IP+port, that clients use for their connection. Launch the server so now its accessible. How do I launch the server application when on hosting? Is there some kind of interface, for example if I want to relaunch the application(called for example server.exe).
3. As I said - clients need to know servers IP and port. So the hosting will give me IP+port that will be accessible for my clients (and I use this IP also on my server)?

I know these questions are kinda basic, but networking is new world for me and deployment of the networked stuff is also a part of it, so would like to understand the proccess.

Comment: I am not well experienced in this, but as far as I know you rent a dedicated server and use remote desktop application (which is built-in on Windows) to connect to it and log-in with your account data, there you do same things you do with your own PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I know about Servers. I have my own Server, but never cared about single Application hosting. There also could be other possibilities.

1. It is not important that it's C++. It is important, for which operating system you compile it. There are good chances, that your server code **could** be platform independent. (Did you use any Windows libraries?)
   There are hosting Services where you pay for CPU and RAM usage and others where you have your own server with fixed CPU and RAM and fixed price. You can choose between Linux and Windows Servers.
2. The Interface depends on the Service you use. If it's some service for gameservers or something similar, there is probably a nice web interface. If it's a so called root server where you have total control over the Server, chances are, you will do everything via command line. (There are probably also root servers with GUI-Webinterfaces?)
3. IP + Port: Think of the Server as an other Computer. It has a static IP. If you don't change the Server, your Clients know the IP as it will stay the same.
   The Port is more interesting. If you have your own root Server, select the port you like. The application hosting services probably give you a Port. (never used such services)

I hope this helped a bit.